# Two Row Navbar hamburger menu shrinks first row

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create a nav menu.  I want the basic nav to be the second row, and I want some misc. quick links to hang out as a top row.

After wrestling through a few examples and moshing them together I have a solution that seems to be working (see below) with one exception...

As I collapse the the menu the top bar wraps the links just fine... as desired, however once I get the the hamburger menu for a small device my 2nd navbar pushes up and hides the top navbar items.  Grr... I just cant make that behavior stop.

Where should I be looking?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <div id="topBar">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" >
                        <ul class="top-links list-inline">
                            <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contact")"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> CONTACT</a></li>
                            <li class="hidden-xs"><a target="_blank" href="https://get.teamviewer.com/xxxxx"><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i>Quick Support</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </div>



                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @Html.ActionLink("xxxxxxx.Net", "Index", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                       ... menu stuff here removed for simplicity 
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="navbar-header navbar-lower" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse-buttons">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li id="home">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Home2", "Index2", "Home")
                        </li>
                        <li id="about">
                            @Html.ActionLink("About", "Index", "About")
                        </li>
                        <li id="services">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Services")
                        </li>
                        <li id="contact">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Index", "Contact")
                        </li>
                        <li id="portfolio" class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li id="1columnportfolio">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("1 Column Portfolio", "OneColumn", "Portfolio")
                                </li>
                                <li id="2columnportfolio">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("2 Column Portfolio", "TwoColumn", "Portfolio")
                                </li>
                                <li id="3columnportfolio">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("3 Column Portfolio", "ThreeColumn", "Portfolio")
                                </li>
                                <li id="4columnportfolio">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("4 Column Portfolio", "FourColumn", "Portfolio")
                                </li>
                                <li id="singleportfolioitem">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Single Portfolio Item", "SingleItem", "Portfolio")
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="blog" class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li id="bloghome1">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Blog Home 1", "Home1", "Blog")
                                </li>
                                <li id="bloghome2">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Blog Home 2", "Home2", "Blog")
                                </li>
                                <li id="blogpost">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Blog Post", "Post", "Blog")
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="other" class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Other Pages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li id="fullwidthpage">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Full Width Page", "FullWidth", "Other")
                                </li>
                                <li id="sidebarpage">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Sidebar Page", "Sidebar", "Other")
                                </li>
                                <li id="faq">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "Faq", "Other")
                                </li>
                                <li id="404">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("404", "FourOhFour", "Other")
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
            </div>


    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will or give you some ideas if nothing else. You could place these links above the `navbar-header` so there fixed with the rest of the `navbar` and are out of the way of the `collapse` functionality. It does take some minor CSS but might be the easier option. Hope it helps.

See example Snippet and FullPage and reduce your browser.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.nav.navbar-top > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav.navbar-top > li > a:hover,
.nav.navbar-top > li > a:focus {
  background: none;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav.navbar-top span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="nav navbar-top">
      <li class="navbar-text"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span>CONTACT</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-text"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link"><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i> <span>QUICK SUPPORT</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-text pull-right"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <span>LOGIN</span></a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
    galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
    containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for your response.  My brain is fried for today.  I'll try this tomorrow.